# How to connect to MQTT over wss with swift?

Tags: swift, mqtt

I´m using CocoaMQTT and trying to connect to a MQTT service, with the following code:

```
    let clientID = "CocoaMQTT-" + String(ProcessInfo().processIdentifier)
    //This is myHost: wss://myserver.test:9001
    let mqtt = CocoaMQTT(clie.ntID: clientID, host: "myserver.test", port: 9001)
    mqtt.keepAlive = 10000
    mqtt.username = "username"
    mqtt.password = "password"
    mqtt.enableSSL = true
    mqtt.delegate = self
    mqtt.connect()
    mqtt.autoReconnect = true
```

I get the error: Error Domain=GCDAsyncSocketErrorDomain Code=7 "Socket closed by remote peer" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Socket closed by remote peer}

Does CocoaMQTT support wss or only tcp? If it doesnt support, is there any other client for swift?

Comment: Can this be related to a selfSigned certificate issue?

Comment: I don´t think so @pan I guess it only needs the user and password

Answer (score 0):

This is a example from [CocoaMQTT](https://github.com/CrazyWisdom/CocoaMQTT/blob/master/Example/Example/ViewController.swift). Maybe it helps.

```
    let clientID = "CocoaMQTT-\(animal!)-" + String(ProcessInfo().processIdentifier)
    mqtt = CocoaMQTT(clientID: clientID, host: "127.0.0.1", port: 8883)
    mqtt!.username = ""
    mqtt!.password = ""
    mqtt!.willMessage = CocoaMQTTWill(topic: "/will", message: "dieout")
    mqtt!.keepAlive = 60
    mqtt!.delegate = self
    mqtt!.enableSSL = true

    let clientCertArray = getClientCertFromP12File(certName: "client-keycert", certPassword: "MySecretPassword")

    var sslSettings: [String: NSObject] = [:]
    sslSettings[GCDAsyncSocketManuallyEvaluateTrust as String] = NSNumber(value: true)
    sslSettings[kCFStreamSSLCertificates as String] = clientCertArray

    mqtt!.sslSettings = sslSettings
```

Comment: I dont need certificate to connect to the broker. I found a way to connect with MQTT-Client-Framework. But thanks

Comment: @NathanMartins you were able to hook up MQTT with sockets?

Comment: @hacker_1989 yes, I'm using this [MQTT-Client-Framework](https://github.com/novastone-media/MQTT-Client-Framework)

Comment: @NathanBarreto did you get `Property 'SR_SSLPinnedCertificates' not found on object of type 'NSMutableURLRequest *'` error in `MQTTWebsocketTransport` class when using MQTT-Client-Framework? I'm do as their tutorial on github to use `pod 'MQTTClient/Websocket'` instead of `pod 'MQTTClient'` because I'm using wss connection

Comment: @Bad_Developer I don't recall having that problem. Maybe something changed  since I used it back then

Comment: @NathanBarreto So, do you have any advice for me? I'm stuck with it.

Comment: @Bad_Developer unfortunately not. It has been a long time since I developed with this, sorry.